# Accelerated emulator xamarin

Tags: macos, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-mac, xamarin-android-player

i trying to start accelerated emulator for android in visual studio for mac ( Xamarin project ), but it always tell me that emulator will start without acceleration, and i did create device with x86, downloaded all that it requires but still nothing.
Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks very much

Comment: What is your macOS version? Have you checked the official docs page for the troubleshoot?

Comment: Is Intel's HAXM installed? https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS

Comment: Try Genymotion for mac https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/

Comment: You also could refer to following link step by step, if you enable these settings.https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/is-your-android-emulator-just-too-slow

Comment: I have also encountered this on my mac. In VS Mac, click Tools > Device Manager, then try and start the emulator manually and then run your project. I know it's not really a fix, but this should allow you to run your application.